# MiKTeX Portable not working out of the box

Tags: miktex, texlive, latexmk, perl

The error message I'm getting is `MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'perl.exe'`, and I'm aware this means I need Perl installed. But if I search the TeX Live distribution path I have on disk, it doesn't have `perl.exe` either, yet it's working flawlessly without installing anything or playing with path.

The reason I have a problem with this is I want this whole thing to be portable. VSCode is portable.Even MiKTeX itself is portable. But if I had to install an entire language onto a system just to get it working that would kinda defeat the whole purpose. Any workaround here? If not, guess TeX Live is the way to go. Which I'd have no problem with, but that thing takes up 6 gigs..

Comment: texlive has a (small) perl included, it is in 2020/ltpkg/tlperl.

Comment: You're right it does! I didn't see it because I was searching in the `bin/win32` dir. How is it able to find it when only `bin/win32` is in system's (or, in my case, VSCode's) environment? Can the same be done with MiKTeX?